# How to make a patch (generator) self running in Bitwig grid?

Tags: bitwig-grid

I'd like to make a generator in Bitwig grid that runs on its own without requiring any note input.  For some reason, phase shows that it's moving from 0->1 but it doesn't effect anything it's routed into?  What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a self running patch, you must have voices set to "Mono" with no voice stacking.  The reason for this is that *in a non-mono context voices are created as needed and don't persist*.

With the settings described above (and shown below), phase will begin acting as expected within its routings.

[image]